# Write the content of head in a paragraph with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to write the contents of `<head>` inside a `<p>` using Javascript for an exercise.

I tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
var contentHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].innerHTML; 
document.getElementById('paragraph1').innerHTML = contentHead;
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? The contents of the `<head>` tag are typically things like `<title>` and `<link>` -- things that have no visible representation.

Comment: Maybe you should put that HTML as text: `document.getElementById('paragraph1').textContent=contentHead;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.outerHTML`. E.g.

```js
const paragraph = document.getElementById("my-paragraph");
paragraph.textContent = document.head.outerHTML;
```

Edit: As [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) pointed out, we have changed from `.innerHTML` to `.textContent`. This is because using `.innerHTML` will actually *render* the content into the paragraph, causing any scripts to run etc. If you want to be able to view the source rather than execute the content, you must use `textContent`.

Comment: You should note that you've changed the OP's code to set `textContent` rather than `innerHTML` and why...

Comment: @CremCaramello If I helped, please could you accept this answer by pressing the checkmark button! It will help other people who may have this issue, but it will also give me some reputation ;)

Comment: @aabbccsmith Done! Sorry but i'm new to Stackoverflow